# possible collectionName values for System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.GetSchema(string collectionName)

Tags: c#, oledbconnection

The code below works swimingly.
I'm not trying to accomplish anything specific. 
I am however; convinced that there must be more possible values for the `collectionName` parameter. Does someone know the full list of possible values?

```
void Foo(string pathToAccessDb)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; "
        + "Data Source=" + pathToAccessDb;
    DataTable tables = conn.GetSchema("Tables");
    DataTable columns = conn.GetSchema("Columns");
    //DataTable other = conn.GetSchema("other values ???");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The valid values for `GetSchema`'s collectionName parameter are found in the [OleDbMetaDataCollectionNames Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbmetadatacollectionnames.aspx).